# iOS: How to get stack trace of an unhandled std::exception?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, crash, crash-reports

If an unhandled `NSException` is thrown, the stack trace has a section like this:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x32bd688f __exceptionPreprocess + 163
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34b7b259 objc_exception_throw + 33
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32bd65c5 -[NSException init] + 1
3   Foundation                      0x37296bd7 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 263
...
```

But if `std::exception` is thrown, I get only this:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x34f2632c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31e4c208 pthread_kill + 48
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31e45298 abort + 88
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33bcaf64 abort_message + 40
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33bc8346 default_terminate() + 18
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x349f4368 _objc_terminate + 164
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33bc83be safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 70
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33bc844a std::terminate() + 14
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33bc981e __cxa_rethrow + 82
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x349f42a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6
10  CoreFoundation                  0x329a5506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
11  CoreFoundation                  0x329a5366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
12  GraphicsServices                0x32af2432 GSEventRunModal + 130
13  UIKit                           0x34f84cce UIApplicationMain + 1074
14  APP_NAME                            0x00086b10 main (main.m:68)
15  APP_NAME                        0x00071b98 start + 32
```

How do I get the exact crash info from this crash log?

Update --

I've given HockeyApp a shot, but it has the same limitation as iTunes crash logs - it doesn't tell me the stack for an unhandled C++ exception.

Comment: Are you using a third party tool like crittercism, or testflightapp to get the reported crashes. You have to upload a dsym file and then it will symbolicate the crashes and it will show you the exact line where the crash occurred. To find the dsym file, you can right click the .ipa file in the organizer window or where ever you stored it and right click and show Contents.

Comment: I'm not using any third party tool. Can you recommend one? Also, I suspect these tools might not handle C++ exceptions - do you know of anyone that does?

Comment: Not sure about that. But here you go, there is another question similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883069/how-to-decode-a-dsym-file-crash-log

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What you're seeing is an unfortunate quirk of AppKit and UIKit. Both iOS and OS X have an exception handler in `CFRunLoop` that traps all uncaught exceptions. On OS X, the handler displays the exception to the user with a dialog box, but on iOS, the handler simply rethrows the exception.

Objective-C exceptions, as implemented by `NSException`, save their backtraces within the exception object right before the actual "throw" happens, as part of `[NSException init]` (or a similar initializer method). Unfortunately, C++ exceptions don't do the same. Normally, a C++ exception has a backtrace because the runtime library detects that there's no `catch` and immediately calls `std::terminate`, which in turn calls `abort()`, leaving the entire call stack intact, like so:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff93ef8d46 __kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff89968df0 abort + 177
2   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8beb5a17 abort_message + 257
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8beb33c6 default_terminate() + 28
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff8a196887 _objc_terminate() + 111
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8beb33f5 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 8
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8beb3450 std::terminate() + 16
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00007fff8beb45b7 __cxa_throw + 111
8   test                            0x0000000102999f3b main + 75
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff8e4ab7e1 start + 1
```

However, when the run loop exception handler traps the exception, execution resumes normally within the `catch` block. The original backtrace is therefore lost. The rethrow subsequently calls `std::terminate`, but at this point, the call stack reflects the run loop exception handler.

To get a backtrace from a C++ exception in this circumstance, you have to throw an exception object which mimics `NSException` and reads the call stack as part of its constructor, and make sure that all exceptions thrown in your code do the same. `std::exception` doesn't do this, and it's not at all likely that any third-party code you're using will either.

File a bug with Apple asking them to remove the `CFRunLoop` exception handler, or at least provide an API for shutting it off. There is no API, not even an SPI, for doing this right now.

Comment: Is there any way to get basic exception information (like the info in `exception::what()`), without actually catching the exception, in a signal handler for SIGABRT?

Comment: Has anyone filed a bug with Apple?  How would one throw an C++ exception that mimics NSException?

Comment: I filed a bug with Apple. Open Radar equivalent: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=4943586562932736

Answer (score 4):

I've had luck with improving mpipe3's answer.

In my main method, I use a try-catch to get the C++ exception and then call a `dispatch_sync` on `dispatch_get_global_queue`. Now the full stack trace with line numbers will show on Crashlytics (crash manager).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

@autoreleasepool {
    @try{
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppControllerClassName");
    } @catch (NSException *exception) {/* Catch any uncaught exceptions and print out a friendly call stack. Instead of an ugly memory addresses. */
        NSString * message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Uncaught exception %@ : %@\n %@", exception.name, exception.reason, [exception callStackSymbols]];
        [LogManager e:@"main.m" Message:message Exception: exception];
        @throw;
    } @catch (...){
        //Attempt to get the correct stacktrace for C++ exceptions.
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
            @throw;
        });
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

This works as it avoids the CFRunLoop exception handler by using GCD to throw the exception.

Comment: Seems this solution doesn't always work. But it's the best I've come up with.

Comment: I realize this is 3 years later ... But any chance you recall under what scenarios your approach didn't work ? I am in a similar situation ...

Comment: I found it didn't like C++ thrown exceptions a lot of the time. But unsure why it works sometimes and not others.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Gwynne Raskind answer you can avoid the CFRunLoop exception handler by using GCD to dispatch a call to a block of C++ code synchronously:

```
namespace
{
    void MyThrowingCode()
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("My Exception");
    }

}

- (void)objcHandlerCalledFromARunLoop
{
   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        MyThrowingCode();
         });
}
```

You might need to create your own queues rather than using a single shared queue.

The crash log looks like this:

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3aa39350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a9affb2 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a9ec366 abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39f94dda abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39f92094 default_terminate() + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a545a70 _objc_terminate() + 168
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39f92118 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39f921b0 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39f9359a __cxa_throw + 118
9   Test                            0x000fddfc MyThrowingCode() (MainViewController.mm:177)
10  Test                            0x000fe38c __35-[MainViewController toolsClick:]_block_invoke (MainViewController.mm:184)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a95f5d8 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a962776 _dispatch_sync_f_invoke + 22
13  Test                            0x000fde90 -[MainViewController toolsClick:] (MainViewController.mm:183)
14  UIKit                           0x34744082 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 66
15  UIKit                           0x3474410c -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 116
16  UIKit                           0x34744082 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 66
17  UIKit                           0x34744036 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
18  UIKit                           0x34744010 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 40
19  UIKit                           0x347438c6 -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 498
20  UIKit                           0x34743db4 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 484
21  UIKit                           0x3466c5f4 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 520
22  UIKit                           0x346598dc -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 376
23  UIKit                           0x346591ea _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 6194
24  GraphicsServices                0x363715f4 _PurpleEventCallback + 588
25  GraphicsServices                0x36371222 PurpleEventCallback + 30
26  CoreFoundation                  0x3281f3e4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
27  CoreFoundation                  0x3281f386 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 134
28  CoreFoundation                  0x3281e20a __CFRunLoopRun + 1378
29  CoreFoundation                  0x32791238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
30  CoreFoundation                  0x327910c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
31  GraphicsServices                0x36370336 GSEventRunModal + 70
32  UIKit                           0x346ad2b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
33  Test                            0x00120462 main (main.mm:55)
34  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a972b1c start + 0
```

Answer (score -2):

looks like the exception is happening from inside UIApplicationMain()... You could try converting your main.m file to a main.mm file, and doing this:

```
int main(...)
{
    try
    {
        return UIApplicationMain(...);
    }
    catch( exception e )
    {
        cerr < e.what() ;
    }
}
```

I didn't actually *try* it, however...